# Create new table with a subset of fields from the original table in arcgis desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am using ArcGIS Desktop/ArcMap. I have a table with over 500 columns. I want to create a table off of that table that contains only 3 out of the 500 columns. I see a "Make Table View" tool in the toolbox, but I have to manually uncheck all of the fields that I don't want visible. There appears to be no option to unselect/select all.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the layer in table of contents and choose properties. When the layer properties window opens, select the Fields tab. There is an all fields on and all fields off button. Click the all fields off button, then select the 3 fields you want turned on.

[image: All Fields Off Button]

Once you have selected your fields, go ahead and click OK to close the window. Go to the attribute table of that layer and you'll see that now only your 3 columns are in view. At this point, you can just export the table. Drop down the table options button and choose export.

[image: Table Options]

Export the table as a dBase file type. Once you run the export, go to where you saved it, and change the filename tag from .dbf to .xls and it will now open in Excel for further manipulation.